# Junit запись version

Tags: maven, junit

Подскажите почему в некоторых случая в `dependency` пишут `<version>4.12</version>`, а в некоторых `<version>${junit.version}</version>`?
В чем суть второй записи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом случае номер версии задаётся прямо, во втором - через переменную.

В pom-файле можно объявить блок со свойствами, например:

```
<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <main-class>demo.myapp.MyApp</main-class>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
</properties>
```

И затем использовать эти свойства вместо явно заданных значений. Например, для указания версии junit, вместо явного константного значения `4.12` используется переменная `${junit.version}`

Этот способ удобен в тех случаях, когда то или иное значение используется во многих местах. Чтобы не менять везде руками, меняем только в одном месте, в блоке объявления свойств.